# Find value from columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets.

Data

```
Column A   Column B    Column C     Column D     Column E

1234
```

Sheet 1

```
Cell N3 = 1234
```

I am using this code to try and find the value in columns A-E.

But for some reason it always returns the wrong result.

```
Set c = Selection.Find(What:=Worksheets(1).Range("N3").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Full Code:

```
Sub PhoneBook()
'Start Phone Book Directory Code
Dim Contact As String
Dim Email As String
Dim Phone As String
Dim Fax As String

'Start FIND
Dim c As Variant

With Worksheets("Contacts").Range("A2:E10000")

Set c = Selection.Find(What:=Worksheets(1).Range("N3").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


If c Is Nothing Then

'Introduce FailSafe, escape code if no result found
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest").Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Close").Visible = False
'ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="SecretPassword"

Else

'Check values are not blank
If c.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
Contact = "Contact: " & c.Offset(0, 1).Value & Chr(10)
Else
Contact = "Contact: No Contact Held" & Chr(10)
End If

If c.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "" Then
Email = "Email: " & c.Offset(0, 2).Value & Chr(10)
Else
Email = "Email: No Email Held" & Chr(10)
End If

If c.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "" Then
Phone = "Phone: " & c.Offset(0, 3).Value & Chr(10)
Else
Phone = "Phone: No Phone Held" & Chr(10)
End If

If c.Offset(0, 4).Value <> "" Then
Fax = "Fax: " & c.Offset(0, 4).Value
Else
Fax = "Fax: No Fax Held"
End If

If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
what_found = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
Else
what_found = c.Value
End If

'Show Contacts
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("I2").Value = "Hello," & vbNewLine & "Have you tried to contact " & what_found & " about your issue?" & vbNewLine _
& Contact & Email & Phone & Fax

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest").TextFrame.AutoSize = True
CenterShape ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest")
RightShape ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Close")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest").Visible = True

'Show Close Button
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Close").OnAction = "HideShape"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Close").Visible = True

'Protect sheet
'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SecretPassword", userinterfaceonly:=True
'ActiveSheet.Shapes("Suggest").Locked = True

End If
End With


End Sub




Public Sub CenterShape(o As Shape)
o.Left = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(1).Left + (ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width / 2 - o.Width / 2)
o.Top = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(1).Top + (ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height / 2 - o.Height / 2)
End Sub

Public Sub RightShape(o As Shape)
o.Left = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest").Left + (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest").Width / 1.01 - o.Width / 1.01)
o.Top = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest").Top + (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Suggest").Height / 30 - o.Height / 30)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to look within `Worksheets("Contacts").Range("A2:E10000")`, remove `Selection` and leave `set c = .Find(...`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeeped suggested, remove the Selection object for your range and instead use the range you defined at the “With” statement. Also, I changed the “After” argument to be a reference to the first cell in the range defined at the “With” statement; and, the “LookIn” argument was changed to be xlValues.

```
...
With Worksheets("Contacts").Range("A2:E10000")

Set c =.Find(What:=Worksheets(1).Range("N3").Value, After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)    
...
```

This search looks at all the columns from A to E. The Find method could return a reference to a cell in a column other than column A if it found a matching value. This may be producing some unusual results for the rest of your code because you are using offset to get the other contact numbers. You may want to consider defining constants for each column and use those with a call to the Cells property using the a constant for the "Column" parameter.

For Example:

Declare your constants for the columns at the beginning of Phonebook().

```
Const lCOLUMN_EMAIL as long = 3
```

Use the Cells property for returning values as with the email example below:

```
If .Cells(c.Row, lCOLUMN_EMAIL).Value <> "" Then
Email = "Email: " & .Cells(c.Row, lCOLUMN_EMAIL).Value & Chr(10)
Else
Email = "Email: No Email Held" & Chr(10)
End If
```

Limit your search to the A column or which ever column contains the values. (Ignore this part if you want to search all the cells in all the columns.)

```
Set c = .Columns(1).Find(What:=Worksheets(1).Range("N3").Value, After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not use selection. it check range only in selection.
if you know the range to be checked as With Worksheets("Contacts").Range("A2:E10000") then 
Change the code as shown below

Set c = .Find(What:=Worksheets(1).Range("N3").Value, After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)